# Remove duplicate rows according to the attribute in google BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have one table called: result
I am using BigQuery to select the data from GA

```
SELECT
  Date,
  totals.pageviews,
  h.transaction.transactionId,
  h.item.itemQuantity,
  h.transaction.transactionRevenue,
  totals.bounces,
  fullvisitorid,
  totals.timeOnSite,
  device.browser,
  device.deviceCategory,
  trafficSource.source,
  channelGrouping,
  h.page.pagePath,
  h.eventInfo.eventCategory,
  device.operatingSystem
FROM
  `atomic-life-148403.126959513.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS h
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN REPLACE(CAST(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR) AS STRING), '-','')
  AND CONCAT('intraday_', REPLACE(CAST(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY) AS STRING), '-',''))
  ORDER BY
  date  DESC
```

[image]

There are some records duplicated. How to remove the duplicated record from the table?

I would like to get the following results.
[image]

Comment: you actually want to find and delete the rows, or just hide them from query results? If the latter, use DISTINCT. If the former, it's going to get a little more complex.

Comment: how to only select the distinct row? as itemquentity and revenue are seperated from each other

Answer (score 4):

You could use ROW_NUMBER

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY transactionid ORDER BY 
transactionid) ROW FROM [YourTable]) 

DELETE [YourTable] 
FROM [YourTable]
JOIN CTE ON [YourTable].transactionid ON CTE.transactionid
                              WHERE CTE.ROW > 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) analytic function like

```
select * from (
select *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY transactionid ORDER BY transactionid) rownum
from result ) xxx
where rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT
  Date,
  totals.pageviews,
  h.transaction.transactionId,
  h.item.itemQuantity,
  h.transaction.transactionRevenue,
  totals.bounces,
  fullvisitorid,
  totals.timeOnSite,
  device.browser,
  device.deviceCategory,
  trafficSource.source,
  channelGrouping,
  h.page.pagePath,
  h.eventInfo.eventCategory,
  device.operatingSystem
FROM
  `atomic-life-148403.126959513.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS h
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN REPLACE(CAST(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR) AS STRING), '-','')
  AND CONCAT('intraday_', REPLACE(CAST(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY) AS STRING), '-',''))
  ORDER BY
  date  DESC
```

As you can see  - I just added DISTINCT to your SELECT - see more about [`SELECT and its modifiers`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select-list) for BigQuery Standard SQL

Answer (score 1):

Using a `GROUP BY` with all of your selected columns should get rid of any true duplicate rows in your results:

```
SELECT
  Date,
  totals.pageviews,
  h.transaction.transactionId,
  h.item.itemQuantity,
  h.transaction.transactionRevenue,
  totals.bounces,
  fullvisitorid,
  totals.timeOnSite,
  device.browser,
  device.deviceCategory,
  trafficSource.source,
  channelGrouping,
  h.page.pagePath,
  h.eventInfo.eventCategory,
  device.operatingSystem
FROM
  `atomic-life-148403.126959513.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS h
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN REPLACE(CAST(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 
YEAR) AS STRING), '-','')
  AND CONCAT('intraday_', REPLACE(CAST(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY) AS STRING), '-',''))
GROUP BY
  Date,
  totals.pageviews,
  h.transaction.transactionId,
  h.item.itemQuantity,
  h.transaction.transactionRevenue,
  totals.bounces,
  fullvisitorid,
  totals.timeOnSite,
  device.browser,
  device.deviceCategory,
  trafficSource.source,
  channelGrouping,
  h.page.pagePath,
  h.eventInfo.eventCategory,
  device.operatingSystem
ORDER BY
  date  DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select unique rows and delete others:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT * FROM MyTable
) as UniqueRows ON
   MyTable.KeyField= UniqueRows.KeyField
WHERE
   UniqueRows.KeyField IS NULL;
```